# Proving continuity of a convolution using abstract definitions of $L^p$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-measure, convolution

I am interested in understanding whether a certain property of convolution on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ spaces can be understood without measure theory. More particularly, consider the vector spaces $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ of compactly supported real-valued continuous functions, and define the norms
$$
||f||_1:=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|dx,\qquad ||f||_{\infty}:=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)|.
$$
and consider the duals (which are necessarily Banach spaces with the operatorial norm)
$$
\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}):=(C_c(\mathbb{R}),||\cdot||_{L^{\infty}})^*,\qquad L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}):=(C_c(\mathbb{R}),||\cdot||_{L^{1}})^*.
$$
By Holder's Inequality for continuous functions and a soft argument for injectivity we get there are inclusions of $(C_c(\mathbb{R}),||\cdot||_{L^{1}})$ into $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ and of $(C_c(\mathbb{R}),||\cdot||_{L^{\infty}})$ into $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. We then define
$$
L^1(\mathbb{R})=\overline{(C_c(\mathbb{R}),||\cdot||_{L^{1}})}\subset \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}),\qquad C_0(\mathbb{R})=\overline{(C_c(\mathbb{R}),||\cdot||_{L^{\infty}})}\subset L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}).
$$

Now we consider the convolution of continuous compactly supported functions
$$
f*g(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y)g(y)dx.
$$
By Young's Inequality for convolutions we can extend this to continuous maps
$$
*\colon L^1\times C_0\to C_0,\qquad *\colon L^1\times L^1\to L^1.
$$
In addition, if $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)g(x)dx$ and $f^r(x):=f(-x)$ it is easy to compute that for $f,g,h\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$
$$
\langle f*g,h\rangle=\langle f,g^r*h\rangle.
$$
Thus, one can define a convolution
$$
*\colon \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})\times C_0(\mathbb{R})\to L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})
$$
by specifying $f*g$ to act on $h\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ by
$$
\langle f*g,h\rangle:=\langle f,g^r*h\rangle
$$
and this extends the previous definition.
I believe that the image of this bilinear map is contained in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ (I think this is a standard result in measure theory). I'm wondering if anyone knows how prove this using only knowledge of the convolution on $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ and duality-type arguments.

Comment: What is your definition of $C_0$? Presumably continuous functions which decay to zero? As it stands your definition coincides with that of $L^1$.

Comment: Typo has been fixed. $C_0$ is continuous functions which decay to zero, $\mathcal{M}$ is finite borel measures.

Comment: For those still thinking about these things, I found a nice blog post by T. Tao that accomplishes my goal of defining the convolution of two finite Borel measures weakly: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/computing-convolutions-of-measures/.

Comment: Using distribution theory, convolutions can be defined on a very large class of distributions. Then one route to proving mapping properties is to show that the convolution of two smooth compactly supported functions satisfies an estimate, and then use density to conclude.